# Can I use Raspberry Pi with PiTFT and Wolfson Pi audio card at the same time?

Tags: gpio, audio, screen, pitft, wolfson-audio-card

I have been using my Raspberry Pi with PiTFT 2.8" display. I have recently purchased Wolfson Pi audio card, but I cannot imagine how to make both components (PiTFT and Wolfson Pi) work together.

Links to the mentioned components:

Adafruit PiTFT:
http://www.adafruit.com/products/1601

Wolfson Pi:
http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/wolfson_pi

PiTFT is using several GPIO pins, whereas Wolfson Pi also relies on the 8-pin audio GPIO connector (P5) just below the 2x13pin "big" GPIO.

My line of thinking is: would Wolfson Pi work if I simply led both connections (2x13pin and 8-pin P5) out (my PiTFT is "stuck" to my 2x13pin GPIO)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I was also thinking of "switching" between PiTFT and Wolfson Pi, but without physically replacing the devices -- the most obvious solution seems to have two versions of Raspian ready, but I believe there must be a better solution (software disabling one device for a temporary period?).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you can't use them together.

According to the PiTFT page it uses the SPI interface (SCK, MOSI, MISO, CE0, CE1) as well as GPIO #25 and #24.

The Wolfson Pi also uses the SPI interface on the 26-pin GPIO which means it is also using the CE0 and CE1 pins. It looks like it also uses a number of other GPIO pins but I could not figure out which ones. It may be all but 2 of them.

Since they both use the same pins there is no software solution that will let you use both.

If you really want better sound and the PiTFT I would suggest looking into a USB sound device instead of the Wolfson.

Comment: You have confirmed what I was suspecting. Anyway, would it make sense to prepare two Raspbian versions (on two SD cards) -- one supporting PiTFT and one dedicated to Wolfson. Then at least I wouldn't have to phisically replace the devices.

Comment: You won't be able to switch between the PiTFT and the wolfson without physically removing one and installing the other. But you might want 2 SD cards since the PiTFT requires a custom kernel.